# input string was not in a correct format c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

estoy intentando sacar el resultado de la compra de varios articulos

pero al compilar me mandar el error

> input string was not in a correct format

```
if (rd.Read())
                    {
                        string PA = rd["PrecioActual"].ToString();
                        int Total = int.Parse(PA) * int.Parse(txtCantidad.Text);
                        GrdArticulos.Rows.Add(
                            rd["CodigoArticulo"].ToString(),
                            rd["Titulo"].ToString(),
                            txtCantidad.Text,
                            PA,
                            Total);
                    }
```

ya intente con el int.TryParse pero me dice que no puedo aplicarlo de bool a int

Comment: Verifica si ese valor es nulo, verifica si txtCantidad tiene valor y/o es nulo, de la misma manera para lo demás.

Comment: Primero debes hacer lo que te recomienda fredyfx y luego al Parse incluyele el CultureInfo.

Comment: ya verifique los datos, el textbox se ingresa manual y el string PA da un valor de 8.0000

Answer (score 0):

Bueno fue curioso porque me pregunte si el string PA lo convertia a double, y fue lo que hice... ya me agrega los valores al datagrid

solo cambie la linea

```
double Total = Convert.ToDouble(PA) * Convert.ToInt21(txtCantidad.Text);
```

y listo funciono